# If has post format video show play icon over the thumb. How?

Tags: php, wordpress, widget, custom-post-type

i am just working with the custom post features and want to achieve a trick which will show play icon over the thumb if the post has post format set to video. How i can do this. I am trying to make it work for one widget that i built which will show only video posts.

This is something i did try and it works but it breaks and hides other thumbs (below).

```
div id="video-block" >


        <?php $recent = new WP_Query(array( 'cat' => $categories, 'showposts' => $posts_num )); while($recent->have_posts()) : $recent->the_post();?>

                <div class="video-entry">


                    <?php if (  (function_exists('has_post_thumbnail')) && (has_post_format( 'video' )) && (has_post_thumbnail()) ) { ?>

                         <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" rel="bookmark" title="<?php the_title(); ?>"><?php the_post_thumbnail( 'video-thumb', array( 'class' => 'img-video' )); ?><span class="playbutton"></span></a>

                        <?php } ?>

                        <div class="video-text">

                            <a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>" rel="bookmark"><?php short_title(68); ?></a>

                        </div><!--video-text-->

                </div> <!--video-entry-->

                    <?php endwhile; ?>

   </div>  <!--videoblock-->
```

Updated part ! is is this correct way of doing it ?

```
<?php if ( has_post_format( 'video' )) : ?>
                         <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" rel="bookmark" title="<?php the_title(); ?>"><?php the_post_thumbnail( 'video-thumb', array( 'class' => 'img-video' )); ?><span class="playbutton"></span></a>
                         <?php else : ?> 
                         <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" rel="bookmark" title="<?php the_title(); ?>"><?php the_post_thumbnail( 'video-thumb', array( 'class' => 'img-video' )); ?></a>
                        <?php endif; ?>
```

Comment: ok i think i'v got it. Can someone just confirm that this is a proper way of doing it ? Check under updated!

Comment: Thanks, never worked with wordpress before 2 weeks ago, so i wanted to be sure. Cheers